# PyQt - How to import .qss file?

Tags: qt, pyqt

How can I import qt's stylesheet .qss file to application?

In HTML we use

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

And how it can be done in PyQt?
Or where can I read about it? Can not google it or find it in Qt's docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The .qss file is a simple text file.
If you want to apply a style sheet to your application,
you have to load the .qss file content in a QString object
and pass it to setStyleSheet() app method.