# how do I use qss in pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtstylesheets

Could anyone tell me how to use a qss file with pyqt4? I tried changing stylesheets in the QTdesigner like [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-designer.html) on the official docs for QT.But it didn't work. I was not sure whether it should be effective for pyqt. And I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335699/pyqt-how-to-import-qss-file) but I don't get the meaning of that. Can anybody tell me how to do it in detail or give me the link of the docs?

Answer (score 5):

## QSS File Code

```
QWidget {
   background-color: #222222;
}

QLineEdit {
   background-color: aliceblue;
   color: #618b38;
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: bold;
}

QLabel {
   background-color: #222222;
   color: #618b38;
}

QPushButton {
   background-color: #8b0000;
   color: #ffffff;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border-style: none;
   height: 25px;
}
```

## Code for GUI

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

__author__ = "Psycho_Coder"


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class MainUiWindow(object):

   def __init__(self):

       #Main Window
       self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

       """
       Using Grid Layouts for Widgets Alignment
       """
       #Grid Layout for Main Grid Layout
       self.maingrid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)

       #Grid Layout for Result Section Layout
       self.resultgird = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

       #Grid Layout for Information section
       self.infogrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

       #Grid Layout for holding all the widgets in place
       self.outergrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

       #Button to clear all test input
       self.clearall = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)

       #Button to show the final result by append
       self.showres = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)

       #Horizontal layout to hold the result section horizontally
       self.horizontal_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

       """
       Show results widgets
       """
       self.fullname = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
       self.result = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

       """
       Get Names info section
       """
       self.firstname = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
       self.lastname = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

       #TextBox to get user input
       self.fname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
       self.lname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)

   def init_gui(self, MainWindow):

       MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")

       MainWindow.setStyleSheet(open("style.qss", "r").read())
       MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(True)
       MainWindow.resize(328, 166)

       self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

       self.maingrid_layout.setObjectName("maingrid_layout")
       self.outergrid.setObjectName("outergrid")
       self.infogrid.setObjectName("infogrid")

       self.firstname.setObjectName("firstname")
       self.infogrid.addWidget(self.firstname, 0, 0, 1, 1)

       self.fname.setObjectName("fname")
       self.infogrid.addWidget(self.fname, 0, 1, 1, 1)

       self.lastname.setObjectName("lastname")
       self.infogrid.addWidget(self.lastname, 1, 0, 1, 1)

       self.lname.setObjectName("lname")
       self.infogrid.addWidget(self.lname, 1, 1, 1, 1)

       self.outergrid.addLayout(self.infogrid, 0, 0, 1, 1)

       self.fullname.setObjectName("fullname")

       self.result.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 16777215))
       self.result.setObjectName("result")

       self.resultgird.setObjectName("resultgird")
       self.resultgird.addWidget(self.fullname, 0, 0, 1, 1)
       self.resultgird.addWidget(self.result, 0, 1, 1, 1)

       self.outergrid.addLayout(self.resultgird, 1, 0, 1, 1)

       self.showres.setObjectName("showres")
       self.clearall.setObjectName("clearall")

       self.horizontal_layout.setObjectName("horizontal_layout")
       self.horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.showres)
       self.horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.clearall)

       self.outergrid.addLayout(self.horizontal_layout, 2, 0, 1, 1)
       self.maingrid_layout.addLayout(self.outergrid, 0, 0, 1, 1)

       MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

       self.retranslate_gui(MainWindow)

       #Add signals of clear to LineEdit widgets to clear the texts
       self.clearall.clicked.connect(self.result.clear)
       self.clearall.clicked.connect(self.lname.clear)
       self.clearall.clicked.connect(self.fname.clear)
       self.showres.clicked.connect(self.__name)

       QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

   def __name(self):
       name = self.fname.text() + " " + self.lname.text()
       self.result.setText("" + name + "")

   def retranslate_gui(self, MainWindow):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

       MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Name Concatenation"))
       self.lastname.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Last Name :"))
       self.firstname.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First Name :"))
       self.fullname.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Concatenated Name :-"))
       self.result.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
       self.showres.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show Name!"))
       self.clearall.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear All"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = MainUiWindow()
   ui.init_gui(MainWindow)

   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## Reference

https://codehackersblog.blogspot.com/2015/10/python-simple-pyqt5-gui-example-with-qss.html

Answer (score 2):

You can change stylesheet in Qt in designer or by code.
If you want to load a qss file and set a stylesheet to a widget, you only have to read file and put the read content in the stylesheet and it will work (the file have to be in the correct format of course).

Example:

**style_file.qss**

```
QLineEdit{border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color: rgb(125,125,125);
        background-color: rgba(255, 134, 134, 150);}
```

Load the file above in your python file and apply that stylesheet with:

```
    qss_file = open('style_file.qss').read()
    ui.your_line_edit_control.setStyleSheet(qss_file)
```

If you want to edit stylesheet by QtDesigner, just put the

```
QLineEdit{border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color: rgb(125,125,125);
        background-color: rgba(255, 134, 134, 150);}
```

in the control right-clicking your control an selecting "*Edit Stylesheet*"

NB: This style will work only for QLineEdit, like is specified in style code...but of course you can use the same way for all widgets (QToolButton, QLabel and so son..)

Comment: I have found the solution myself these days. Just beacuse I was so careless. Thank you very much anyway!